# How to create an ec2 instance using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

Is it possible to create an ec2 instance using boto3 in python?
Boto3 document is not helping here, and I couldn't find any helping documents online. please provide some sample codes/links.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The API has changed but it's right there in the documentation

```
# Boto 3
ec2.create_instances(ImageId='<ami-image-id>', MinCount=1, MaxCount=5)
```

Link to the documentation:

- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/service-resource/create_instances.html
- http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#launching-new-instances

Comment: Do you know if there is a keyword argument to specify the security group? That way I can create the instance, and set the right security group that will let me ssh into the server.

Comment: It should accept a `SecurityGroups=['secgroup', ..]` keyword argument. This [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/136) seems to suggest that `create_instances` is running the classic boto2 `run_instances` behind the scenes so the original parameters for `run_instances` should be valid. See the [documentation](http://botocore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances)

Comment: Thanks mate, will give it a shot

Comment: Hi. The docs are pretty skimpy and vague. If I want the new instances to be c3.xlarge, how do I set the parameters?

Comment: Add this keyword argument to `create_instances`: `InstanceType="c3.xlarge"`

Comment: How can you specify instance name? Instances are created without name...

Comment: @Brian, the name of an instance is just a tag with the key "Name". See `create_tags` for usage info.

Comment: Why isn't Amazon's own cli as simple as Boto3? Are they thinking of creating a new job branch(or already created?)?

Comment: `ec2` is `boto3.client` or `boto3.resource` type?

Answer (score 21):

You can run the code I used from the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances). You can add or remove parameters as per your requirements, but this is what you would normally require:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

response = client.run_instances(
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
            'Ebs': {

                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'VolumeSize': 8,
                'VolumeType': 'gp2'
            },
        },
    ],
    ImageId='ami-6cd6f714',
    InstanceType='t3.micro',
    MaxCount=1,
    MinCount=1,
    Monitoring={
        'Enabled': False
    },
    SecurityGroupIds=[
        'sg-1f39854x',
    ],
)
```

Comment: How will I know if the instance has been created and ready for login?

Comment: You would have to run a DescribeInstances API call with the Instance ID you get from the RunInstances API call.

Comment: However there are no API calls that would let you know if the instance is ready to login.

Comment: Worked like charm for me

Answer (score 11):

The link you're really looking for in the documentation is the [`create_instances()` method of the ServiceResource object](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances). This is the type of object you are calling if you create an EC2 resource like this:

```
s = boto3.Session(region_name="us-west-1")
ec2 = s.resource('ec2')
...
instance = ec2.create_instances(**y_kwargs)
```

This contains a more detailed example and a longer list of available parameters.

You can also get parameter values for AWS instances that are already running using the AWS command line interface:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances
```

This prints out a JSON file from which relevant parameters can be extracted and passed to the `create_instances()` method. (Or, you can use a boto client and call the [`describe_instances()` method](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances).)

(Note: If you're wondering what the difference is between the Client and the Resource, they serve different purposes for the same end - the client is a lower-level interface while the Resource is a higher-level interface.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the differences between Client and Resource!

Comment: How did you figure this out? I saw ec2.create_instances in the documentation but I didn't know what ec2 was.

Answer (score 6):

Refer to API docs has all available options to create instance

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Subnet.create_instances

Answer (score 2):

If your running from your windows computer you need configure AWS Cli with proper EC2 permisssion to launch instance.

#

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-5eb63a32',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
)
print(instance[0].id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='')

conn = ec2.run_instances(ImageId='<ami-image-id>', 
                         InstanceType='<instance-type>',
                         MinCount=1, 
                         MaxCount=5
                            )
```