# How can I run a more powerful AWS EC2 instance that starts and stops when I receive a request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I want to use a very small EC2 instance that is always ready, but when a request is made, I will have very heavy computations to run and would like to use a more expensive instance to run the task and then shut down. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Edit: By heavy computations, I mean multithreaded image manipulations. The time it takes to run scales linearly with the number of CPUs.

Comment: **Consider AWS Lambda.**

And it can run with some real horsepower with up to 3GB of ram (allocated to the function call), 5 minute duration.

If these computations can run in parallel, then you could do an async call of a number of lambda calls and have unlimited power, and just pick up the results in S3 when done.

Comment: Could you expand further about the type of work you want it to do? How long would the "very heavy computations" need to run? AWS Lambda might be suitable, but it depends on your needs. Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help - added more details to the question.  I like the idea of calling multiple instances of AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different use cases that could lead someone to this question, so here are a few options:

### 1. Auto Scaling Group in Elastic Beanstalk

Something like [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) would make sense if you're trying to handle load balancing / capacity provisioning for an app across EC2 instances.  You can use an auto scaling group and triggers to automatically provision more nodes as needed on the fly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html

### 2. boto3 ec2.create_instances

To answer your question more literally, you could use boto3 to provision an EC2 instance using the `create_instances` call whenever the condition you have in mind exists in an incoming request.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863768/how-to-create-an-ec2-instance-using-boto3) and the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#launching-new-instances).

EC2 billing used to be 1-hour minimum but they've recently changed that to be [1-minute minimum](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/), so this could be a viable route depending on your workload.

### 3. boto3 Lambda.Client.invoke

If you wanted to do something similar on AWS Lambda, you can also do that with boto3 via the `invoke` call on the Lambda client ([docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke)).